# Calculate definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following integral that I want to calculate in Mathematica:

$$\int_x^y t^z \ln t \, \mathrm{d}t,$$

where $z$ is an integer and $0<x<y$.

What code can calculate this integral?

Comment: Have a look at [Integrate](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=Integrate).

Comment: Yes I already looked there but cannot find how to include 0<<

Comment: `Integrate` has an option [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html#22496) which you can use to specify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both gives you same answer**

You can set up **Global** `Assumption` like this

```
$Assumptions = {{0 < x < y}, {Element[z, Integers]}}
f[z_] = t^z; 
g[t_] = Log[t]; 
Integrate[f[z]*g[t], {t, x, y}]
```

Also, you can use it **inside** `Integrate` like this

```
f[z_] = t^z; 
g[t_] = Log[t]; 
Integrate[f[z]*g[t], {t, x, y}, 
Assumptions -> {{0 < x < y}, {Element[z, Integers]}}]
```